# Python if test condition fails when used with or

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

Greetings python experts. I had written an if condition as follows that fails to be false for objects that should be false. I am writing in python 3.8.5. Note instance_list in this example contains a list of resources that are in various states. I only want to append vm_instance_list with resources that are not in a TERMINATED or TERMINATING state.

```
instance_results = compute_client.list_instances(
    compartment_id = compartment_id).data
vm_instance_list = []
for instance in instance_results:
    if instance.lifecycle_state != "TERMINATED" or instance.lifecycle_state != "TERMINATING:
        vm_instance_list.append(instance)
```

The above code appends vm_instance_list with every object in the list instance_results, aka each condition is interpreted as True for objects that are in a TERMINATED or TERMINATING lifecycle state. I have had to re-write to nest the if conditions, which works.

```
for instance in instance_results:
    if instance.lifecycle_state != "TERMINATED:
        if instance.lifecycle_state != "TERMINATING":
            vm_instance_list.append(instance)
```

I have no idea what why I have had to nest the above if statements and would appreciate if anyone could share some insights.

Thanks so much,

- Hank

Comment: you are missing " at end of `if instance.lifecycle_state != "TERMINATED:`

Answer (score 0):

In your first version, the result is ALWAYS true, so every item is appended.
Your second version is only true if both tests are true.

If you want the first version to behave like the second version, you need an 'and' statement, not an 'or'.

Answer (score 0):

Let's trace through your first `if` statement in the case when `instance.lifecycle_state` is equal to `"TERMINATED"`. The condition is as follows:

```py
instance.lifecycle_state != "TERMINATED" or instance.lifecycle_state != "TERMINATING"
```

We can see that the first part of this statement is false (since `lifecycle_state` DOES equal `"TERMINATED"`. The second part is true because `lifecycle_state` indeed does NOT equal `"TERMINATING"`. So this whole expression simplifies to:

```py
False or True
```

which finally simplifies (by the rules of `or`) to be just: `True`. So now we have seen why the body of the `if` is executed in the first case.

If we do a similar process in your second code snippet, we will see that the first condition is False (since `lifecycle_state` DOES equal `"TERMINATED"`. So in this case the second condition is not checked, and the body of the `if` does not execute.

In fact, the second snippet is equivalent to the following condition:

```py
instance.lifecycle_state != "TERMINATED" and instance.lifecycle_state != "TERMINATING"
```

Note that this is very similar to your original snippet, however we've replaced `or` with `and`. In fact, two nested `if` statements like this are equivalent to a single condition where both parts are joined by `and`.

By [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), this condition is also equivalent to:

```py
not (instance.lifecycle_state == "TERMINATED" or instance.lifecycle_state == "TERMINATING")
```

which you may find clearer to understand.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the reference to DeMorgan's Laws. This has given me the clarification I need for future work. Take care.